# How to get HasMap object list?

Tags: android, object, for-loop

I have object called answer. I can fill object with values, but I do not know how to get list of it.

```
public class Answer{

    private HashMap<String, Integer> answer;

    public Answer(HashMap<String, Integer> answer) {
        this.answer = answer;
    }

    public HashMap<String, Integer> getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }
}

final Answer answers = new Answer(new HashMap<String, Integer>() {{
        put("STRING1",1);
        put("STRING2",2);
        put("STRING3",3);
    }});
```

I tried to use for each, but it is not correct. Please advice, how to list it. Thank you.

```
    for (Answer answer:answers) {

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Class Answer:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Answer{

    private HashMap<String, Integer> answer;

    public Answer(HashMap<String,Integer> hashMap) {
        this.answer = hashMap;
    }

    public HashMap<String, Integer> getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }
}
```

Using Class:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class main {

    main(){

        final Answer answers = new Answer(new HashMap<String,Integer>(){{
            put("STRING1",1);
            put("STRING2",2);
            put("STRING3",3);
        }});

        for(HashMap.Entry<String, Integer> entry : answers.getAnswer().entrySet()){
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new main();

    }

}
```

Produces Output:

```
STRING3: 3
STRING1: 1
STRING2: 2
```

Altough if your answers Class isn't going to do anything else id strongly recommend just using a Hashmap and name it answers as currently your answer class only stores a Hashmap without any bennefits

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for! :)